# jquery animation with call back function not working on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-callback

Below is some part of my code I'm using `jquery animation` with call back function.

I want to animate `header` with `top:-141px` after a time gap this should animate and with `top:-63px`.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  

   $("#header").animate({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '-141px',
    },function(){
      $(this).animate({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '-63px',
      })
    });
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

#header{
  height:141px;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  Header section
</header>

<div>
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation method does not support property like `position`, so use css to set it

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {

    $("#header").stop(true).css({
      position: 'fixed'
    }).animate({
      top: '-141px',
    }, function() {
      $(this).animate({
        top: '-63px',
      })
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#header {
  height: 141px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="header">
  Header section
</header>

<div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply but bye your code `header` animate every scroll.

Comment: @Maddy that is because you have it in a scroll handler with condition `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {` - you need to find tune that to match your need